Create FeignClient With Constructor
I know that we can create FeignClient like:
@FeignClient(value = "service-A-client", url = "${service-A-client.url}")
public interface ServiceAClient {

 @PostMapping(value = "/service-A/v1/resource")
    Response getResource(RequestPojo request);
 
}

But I wonder whether I can create it via constructor or not:
public interface ServiceAClient {

 @PostMapping(value = "/service-A/v1/resource")
    Response getResource(RequestPojo request);
 
}

public class FeignConfig {
     
    @Bean
    public ServiceAClient service() {
        return new ... ? is it possible?
    }
}


you mean instantiate / configure feign programatically yourself? There is Feign Builder API that you can use

yes @JAsgarov that is exactly what I want. thank you.

Thanks to @JAsgarov solved with Feign Builder API
public Feign.Builder feignBuilder() {
        return Feign.builder();
    }

